# Поиск элемента в векторе по заданному правилу

Tags: c++

Есть массив структур

```
struct CMyData
{
    int count;
    int w;
    int h;
};

CMyData myArray[100];
```

Есть вектор содержащий несколько индексов этого массива:

```
std::vector<int> indeces;
```

Необходимо найти итератор/индекс на элемент массива `myArray` в котором count максимально и в случае, если таких элементов несколько, то тот элемент, у которого (w*h) минимально.

Хотелось бы это сделать через stl и лямбада-функции

Comment: А для чего вообще нужен `indeces` в этой задаче?

Comment: alexolut, просто дал из реальной задачи,где в indeces хранится выборка элементов из большого списка. По идее это мог бы быть и вектор указателей `std::vector<CMyData*>`, не принципиально. И мне надо в этом списке найти один (первый из нескольких) элемент, удовлетворяющий указанным выше критериям.

Comment: Т.е. это некое подмножество индексов, которые надо рассматривать, а остальные игнорировать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не очень понял для чего в этой задаче нужен `indeces`, поэтому предлагаю решение без него.

```
auto it = std::max_element(std::begin(myArray), std::end(myArray), 
                     [](const auto& l, const auto& r) 
                     {
                         if (l.count != r.count) 
                             return l.count < r.count;
                         else
                             return l.w * l.h > r.w * r.h;
                     });

std::cout << std::distance(std::begin(myArray), it) << '\n';
```

Если `indeces` задают некое подмножество индексов, которые нужно рассматривать, а остальные игнорировать, то код может быть таким:

```
auto it = std::max_element(std::begin(indeces), std::end(indeces), 
                 [](int ln, int rn) 
                 {
                     const CMyData& l = myArray[ln];
                     const CMyData& r = myArray[rn];
                     if (l.count != r.count) 
                         return l.count < r.count;
                     else
                         return l.w * l.h > r.w * r.h;
                 });
std::cout << *it << '\n';
```

Comment: кстати а зачем std::begin() вместо .begin()?
в чем преимущество?

Comment: @Zhihar в общем случае - унификация. В частном случае - из-за трансформации кода с `myArray` в `indeces`. Ведь для сырых массивов нет функций-членов.

Comment: думаю  indeces нужен для того, чтобы не рассматривать все элементы, а только элементы с индексом, указанным в векторе.

Answer (score 0):

спасибо alexolut за ответ

несколько переделал код для своей цели

```
std::vector<int>::iterator it = std::max_element(indeces.begin(), indeces.end(), [myArray](const int id1, const int id2) {
    if (myArray[id1].count != myArray[id2].count)
        return myArray[id1].count < myArray[id2].count;

    return (myArray[id1].w * myArray[id1].h) > (myArray[id2].w * myArray[id2].h);
});
```